# Word2vec TypeError: 'collections.defaultdict' object is not callable

Tags: python, data-science, word2vec

> I am trying to build a word2vec using skip-gram and negative sampling
> However, when I try to build the vocab dictionary, I have encountered an error as written on the title.
> This is actually a sentiment analysis project, but I plan to use word2vec to carry out features extraction before the sentiment analysis.
> Can anyone help me to solve this problem? thank you in advance

```
def vocab(self):
    # sentences: list of sentence token lists
    # [[['here', 'are', 'two', 'reasons', 'companies', 'fail', 'they', 'only', 'do', 'more', 'of', 'the', 'same', 'or', 'they', 'only', 'do', 'what', 's', 'new']], [[]], ...]
    sentences = self.sentences
    vocab = defaultdict(dict)
    vocab_words = ['int']
    vocab['int']['word_count'] = 0 
    vocab_size = 0
    for sent_tokens in sentences:
        for word1 in sent_tokens:
            vocab_size += len(word1)
            for word in word1:
                if not word.isdigit() and word not in vocab:
                    vocab[word]['word_count'] = 1
                    vocab_words.append(word)
                else:
                    if word.isdigit():
                        vocab['int']['word_count'] += 1 
                    else:
                        vocab[word]['word_count'] += 1
    low_freq_words = []
    for word in vocab:
        if vocab[word]['word_count'] < self.min_count:
            low_freq_words.append(word)
    for word in low_freq_words:
        vocab_size -= vocab[word]['word_count']
        del vocab[word]
        vocab_words.remove(word)
    sorted_vocab = []
    for word in vocab:
        sorted_vocab.append((word, vocab[word]['word_count']))
    sorted_vocab.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1], reverse=True)
    for idx, word in enumerate(sorted_vocab):
        vocab[word[0]]['word_freq'] = vocab[word[0]]['word_count'] / vocab_size
        vocab[word[0]]['word_index'] = idx
    return vocab
```

Comment: first of all `defaultdict(dict)` is new for me. Is this self written? I changed it to dict(). After this I got a lot of `KeyError` the dict `vocab` doesn't contain the words. to I added them by `if word not in vocab.keys(): vocab[word]=dict()` then the code run and I got this: `{'here': {'word_count': 1, 'word_freq': 0.05, 'word_index': 3},....`

Comment: full file here:
https://github.com/JYjunyang/FYPDEMO

Comment: @Exciter not actually self written. I modified from a code shared by a github user.

Comment: @Exciter do u mean, it less some code for it to run properly?

Comment: didn't know there is a `from collections import defaultdict` will use it in future for sure. Where did you get your error? If  I set sentence to the comment, and provide a `min_count` the code is running for me.

Comment: @Exciter my error is the vocab() cannot run properly, I wonder is the list I using is the main problem? cuz the list I using is transformed from a dataframe
Example of the list is in the comment I wrote under the method

Comment: I set `sentences = [[['here', 'are', 'two', 'reasons', 'companies', 'fail', 'they', 'only', 'do', 'more', 'of', 'the', 'same', 'or', 'they', 'only', 'do', 'what', 's', 'new']], [[]]]` so basically remove the ... and it worked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243640/discussion-between-exciter-and-user14811578).

Comment: Change Line 194 to `vocabulary = word2vec.vocab` remove the function call of `vocab` it is a bit confusing because the function name and the attribute name are the same.

Comment: Thank you so much @Exciter ! Thank you for being patient to help me solve the problems. Very appreciate your help!! Thank you very much!